# Find Html input inside a Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to find the HTML input text inside a `Gridview`.
But I am getting an error.

**Error**

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**Source Code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width="2%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input id="txtNum" runat="server" value='<%#Eval("num") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind**

```
 HtmlInputText txt1 = (HtmlInputText)gridview1.FindControl("txtNum");
 txt1.Attributes["type"] = "tel";
```

Comment: you can't find like this .. loop gridview rows.. and in that row first column will have that control some thing like this HtmlInputText txt1 = (HtmlInputText)gridview1.rows[0][0].FindControl("txtNum");

Comment: On which event you want to get this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to find the `HtmlInputText` in each row of the gridview.

**Code**

```
if (gridview1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gridview1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        HtmlInputControl txt1 = (HtmlInputControl)gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("txtNum");
        txt1.Attributes["type"] = "tel";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for the future I resolved this way:

---HTML CODE---

```
 <asp:TemplateField Visible="False" ItemStyle-Width="100%">  
                  <ItemTemplate>

<div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">A</span>
  </div>
 <input id="txtMat" type="text" style="width: 100px;" class="form-control" runat="server" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"  placeholder="Matricula" aria-label="Matricula" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" onkeydown="limit(this, 8);" onkeyup="limit(this, 8);"  min="8"/>
</div>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>   </strike>
```

---C# ----

// I needed to send an E-mail using an input text inside griview. in the input text  I type the e-mail address.

```
protected void GridView_Cat_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

HtmlInputText Matricula = GridView_Cat.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtMat") as HtmlInputText;

String address= Matricula.Value;
}
```

You will need:

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```